# Using bootstrap for administrative backend in RefineryCms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, refinerycms

I want to use bootstrap for my edition pages.

I had installed already the gems for using bootstrap and they work pretty good for my site pages.

**gem 'refinerycms-bootstrap'**

**gem 'bootstrap-sass'**

But when I try of use the bootstraps classes for my backend edit form... they are not included.

How I can include the bootstrap for my backend pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it.

Open the file

**config/initializers/refinery/core.rb**

uncomment the lines

# Register extra javascript for backend

config.register_javascript "custom"

# Register extra stylesheet for backend (optional options)

config.register_stylesheet "custom", :media => 'screen'

Then I go to the path **vendor/assets/stylesheets** and I created the file **custom.css.scss**
 and the path **vendor/assets/javascripts** I created the file **custom.js**

*custom.css.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

*custom.js*

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Then I created the file **config/initializers/assets.rb** with this content

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.js )
```

Restart rails server

Now I must to fix some visual issues.